# Have code behind javascript work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: c#, asp.net

In all major modern browsers I can do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Show on pageload')", true);
}
```

When I open the page, it results in a Javascript popup that says 'Show on pageload'.

In Internet Explorer 8, the popup does not appear. What can I do to make the Javascript work in IE 8?

Comment: Do you see any script errors?

Comment: I do not see any script errors.

Comment: have you tried this on multiple computers with IE8? Could be javascript is disabled or something along these lines on the computer you are testing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, nothing should be problematic with the `alert` function in I.E 8.

In your I.E browser -> Right click -> Select View Source and see what is the real generated script.

Comment: YOu are right, the code is generating but it does not fire.